# Calculate the area of rectangles union

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, computational-geometry

I've been given the following task:

> Given N rectangles with edges parallel to axis, calculate the area of the union of all rectangles. The input and output are files specified in program arguments. Input is represented by N lines with 4 numbers separated by spaces, defining 2 opposite vertices of the rectangle. Output file should contain 1 number - the resulting area of the rectangles' union.

Additional constraints:

- \$1 \le N \le 100\$
- \$-10000 \le x1\$, \$y1\$, \$x2\$, \$y2 \le 10000\$
- Memory consumption < 16 MB
- Program parameters should be validated
- Input file format should be validated.

Examples:

Input:

```
1 1 7 7
```

Output:

```
36
```

Input:

```
1 1 3 3  
2 2 4 4
```

Output:

```
7
```

My solution:

```
public class Main {

    private List<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid arguments number\nProgram usage: java Main input output");
        }

        Main computer = new Main();
        long area = computer.computeAreaFromFile(args[0]);
        computer.writeAreaToFile(area, args[1]);
    }

    public long computeAreaFromFile(String inputFileName) {
        rectangles.clear();

        String line;
        try (BufferedReader inputFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFileName))) {
            long area = 0;

            while ((line = inputFileReader.readLine()) != null) {
                Rectangle rectangle = Rectangle.fromString(line);
                area += addRectangleArea(rectangle, false);
            }

            return area;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input file not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (NumberFormatException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input file contains incorrect line");
        }
    }

    private int addRectangleArea(Rectangle newRectangle, boolean isIntersection) {
        int result = 0;

        boolean hasIntersections = false;

        for (Rectangle existingRectangle : rectangles) {
            if (!existingRectangle.contains(newRectangle)) {
                List<Rectangle> complements = existingRectangle.complementOf(newRectangle);
                if (complements.size() > 0) {
                    hasIntersections = true;

                    for (Rectangle complement : complements) {
                        result += addRectangleArea(complement, true);
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!hasIntersections) {
            result += newRectangle.area();
        }

        if (!isIntersection) {
            rectangles.add(newRectangle);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void writeAreaToFile(long area, String outputFileName) {
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFileName))) {
            writer.write(String.valueOf(area));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not open file " + outputFileName);
        }
    }
}

class Rectangle {
    public final int x1;
    public final int y1;
    public final int x2;
    public final int y2;

    public static Rectangle fromString(String input) throws NumberFormatException, IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        String[] splitInput = input.split(" ");

        if (splitInput.length != 4) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }

        return new Rectangle(Integer.valueOf(splitInput[0]),
            Integer.valueOf(splitInput[1]),
            Integer.valueOf(splitInput[2]),
            Integer.valueOf(splitInput[3]));
    }

    public Rectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        this.x1 = Math.min(x1, x2);
        this.y1 = Math.min(y1, y2);
        this.x2 = Math.max(x1, x2);
        this.y2 = Math.max(y1, y2);
    }

    /**
     * Finds a relative complement of the specified rectangle.
     *
     * @param rectangle rectangle to find a complement of.
     * @return {@link List} of the rectangles forming the resulting complement.
     */
    public List<Rectangle> complementOf(Rectangle rectangle) {
        List<Rectangle> intersections = new ArrayList<>();

        if (rectangle.x2 > x1 && x2 > rectangle.x1 && rectangle.y2 > y1 && y2 > rectangle.y1) {
            if (rectangle.y1 <= y1) {
                intersections.add(new Rectangle(rectangle.x1, rectangle.y1, rectangle.x2, y1));
            }

            if (y2 <= rectangle.y2) {
                intersections.add(new Rectangle(rectangle.x1, y2, rectangle.x2, rectangle.y2));
            }

            if (rectangle.x1 <= x1) {
                intersections.add(new Rectangle(rectangle.x1, Math.max(y1, rectangle.y1), x1, Math.min(y2, rectangle.y2)));
            }

            if (x2 <= rectangle.x2) {
                intersections.add(new Rectangle(x2, Math.max(y1, rectangle.y1), rectangle.x2, Math.min(y2, rectangle.y2)));
            }
        }

        return intersections;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates area of this rectangle.
     *
     * @return area of this rectangle.
     */
    public int area() {
        return Math.abs((x1 - x2) * (y1 - y2));
    }

    /**
     * Checks if this rectangle contains the specified rectangle.
     *
     * @param rectangle rectangle to check for.
     * @return true if rectangle inside this, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean contains(Rectangle rectangle) {
        return x1 <= rectangle.x1 && rectangle.x2 <= x2 && y1 <= rectangle.y1 && rectangle.y2 <= y2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Rectangle)) {
            return false;
        }

        Rectangle other = (Rectangle) o;
        return x1 == other.x1 && y1 == other.y1 && x2 == other.x2 && y2 == other.y2;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;

        result = 37 * result + x1;
        result = 37 * result + y1;
        result = 37 * result + x2;
        result = 37 * result + y2;

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Rectangle with x1: %s y1: %s x2: %s y2: %s", x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

I have several questions/considerations:

1. Is the provided solution correct?
2. I assume the complexity of this algorithm is \$O(n^2)\$. Can it be improved?
3. I've overridden `toString()`, `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, although I've never called them (except `toString()` while debugging). Is it bad practise to do so?
4. I feel that comments in javadoc are lame. How can they be improved and are they necessary at all?
5. `computeAreaFromFile()` does 2 things: it reads file content and performs actual calculations. I think this method should be split, however I'm not sure how I could do this.

Answer (score 4):

The time for the approach you gave is in \$O(n ^ 2)\$.

---

Dec. 10, 2018

**Details about a possible solution**

This is Klee's measure problem for \$d = 2\$.

Apparently, an optimal algorithm for this case exists and is called Bentley's algorithm. Its running time is \$O(n \cdot \log(n))\$. However, it seems that the 1977 paper that describes it is unavailable. It uses sweep-line approach and a dynamic 1-d segment tree.

We have \$n\$ axis-aligned rectangles. Our sweep-line moves across \$x\$. We have events along \$x\$ that correspond to start of rectangle and end of rectangle. The intersection of the sweep-line with a collection of rectangles is essentially a 1-d measure problem. We have \$2 \cdot n\$ events with at most \$2 \cdot n\$ distinct x values. We use a 1-d segment tree that we maintain via inserts and deletes to give 1-d measure that we "pull" with delta-\$x\$'s to give incremental contributions to 2-d measure. The costly operations are sort and insert/delete.

Higher dimensions are more difficult to handle. We might then be better served by using higher-dimensional segment tree with intersection queries or an R-tree variant with intersection queries. This would depend on which is larger -- \$d\ \cdot \log(n)\$ or \$\log^{\textrm{max}(d - 1, 1)}(n)\$ for \$d \geq 1\$ -- the former being smaller may imply that R-tree is better; the latter (i.e. we note that this time is with fractional cascading) being smaller implies segment tree is better.

For more details, see the links.

**References**

- Bentley - Algorithms for Klee's rectangle problems (1977) -- possibly unavailable
- Elizarov - Finding missing range in multidimensional domain - Answer (2017)
  https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/73819
- Erickson - Klee's measure problem (1998)
  http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/open/klee.html
- Chlebus - On the Klee's measure problem in small dimensions (1998)

Comment: Wow, I accidentally came across this answer. Super helpful insight!

Answer (score 3):

**Correctness**

(See the update at the end.)

I don't believe your algorithm is correct. Here is the way I would expect to see it solved:

1. Define a function `rectDiff(r,s)` which computes the difference of two rectangles `r` and `s`. It may return an empty list (if `r` is completely contained in `s`), a list of just `r` (if `r` is disjoint from `s`) or a list of two smaller rectangles `r1`, `r2` representing the parts of `r` which do not intersect `s`. This is probably what your `.complementsOf()` method does.
2. Given this `rectDiff` function, I would compute the area like this:

   Pseudo-code:

   ```
   theRects = ...read rects from a file...

   rectangles = []
   totalArea = 0

   for r in theRects:
     pieces = [r]
     for s in rectangles:
       pieces = takeAway(pieces, s)
     for t in pieces:
       totalArea += area(t)
     append r to rectangles

   def takeAway(pieces, s):
     # pieces is a list of (disjoint) rects
     # s is a single rect
     # returns a new list of (disjoint) rects
     newPieces = []
     for t in pieces:
       append rectDiff(t,s) to newPieces
     return newPieces
   ```

   The point is that when considering a new rectangle `r` you need to remove from `r` the overlap with all previous rectangles, and then you can add the area of the surviving complements to the total area.

Your code, however, adds the area of a complement right away to the total area.

**Range trees**

If you employ the ideas in [this article](http://ankitsambyal.blogspot.com/2013/10/finding-overlapping-rectangles-in-given.html), you can use range trees to write the code this way:

```
for r in theRectangles:
  let rlist = the list of rects in rectangles which overlap with r
  pieces = [r]
  for s in rlist:
    pieces = takeAway(pieces, s)
  ...
  add r to rectangles
```

The idea is that using a range tree `rlist` might be a lot smaller than the full list `rectangles`.

**Update**

Your algorithm is probably correct since you recursively call `addRectangleArea()` on each complement piece.

However, there is an inefficiency in the algorithm. Suppose:

```
rectangles = [ r1, r2, r3, ... ]
```

and we are processing a new rectangle `r`. Let

```
cs1 = rectDiff(r, r1) = complements of r compared to r1
    = [ c1, c2, ... ]
```

Your code calls `addRectangleArea(c1)` which then will compute `rectDiff(c1, r1)`. However, this difference will always be empty. When considering `c1` (or `c2` or any rectangle in `cs1`) you can start with `r2` in the `rectangles` list on the recursive call.

Comment: Thanks for the review! You're right about what my `complementsOf()` method does. However, my algorithm does not add area of complements right away, instead I call `addRectangleArea()` recursively with the overlapping part of r, which is basically what you suggest. Apparently I failed to write this in concise way. Thanks for the range trees links, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I see that now. Also see my update.